# Event doesn't fire for dynamically added controls in WebForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface

I have a User Control on my C# web form. The Control in made of another Activex control. The user control is being added dynamically to the form. I have added a double click event for each dynamical added instance of user control. However the double click even is not getting fired.  Below is my code

```
          int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int i, j;
        int[,] Matrica;

        Matrica = new int[n, m];
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a = merlokacionin.X + 5;

            for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                textbox[i, j] = new UserCont();    
                textbox[i, j].Location = new Point(a, b)
                panel3.Controls.Add(textbox[i, j])
                textbox[i, j].DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(dicom_DoubleClick);
                a = a + 105;
            }
            b = b + 105;

    }

   private void dicom_DoubleClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("do something here");
    }



   //I have also tried; 
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int i, j;
        int[,] Matrica;
        Matrica = new int[n, m];
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a = merlokacionin.X + 5;

            for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                textbox[i, j] = new UserCont();    
                textbox[i, j].Location = new Point(a, b)
                panel3.Controls.Add(textbox[i, j])
                textbox[i, j].DoubleClick += new    System.EventHandler(dicom_DoubleClick);
                a = a + 105;
            }
            b = b + 105;

        }

    private void dicom_DoubleClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("do something here");
    }
```

I have even tried adding Double click click event in the User control itself, and even that is not being fired.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When working dynamically created controls, you must re-add the control **no later** than the `Page_Load` method. Otherwise, the event handlers will not "reconnect" nor will the viewstate be restored for the control.

Recreating the controls during `OnInit` is the "correct" place during the page's lifecycle. While the end result is the same, recreating the controls during `Page_Load` forces the page to play "catch up".

If you can provide the relevant code from your page, I can provide you with the implementation. Otherwise, just recreate the dynamic control(s) as I detailed above.

EDIT

> Is there anything else that can be done to fire up event?

Short answer? No, there isn't. You are bound by the asp.net page's lifecycle. If you don't recreate the controls as mentioned above, you will not be able to wire up the button's click event.

The trick here is tracking the controls you have created dynamically so you **can** restore them during `Page_Init`. You can use ViewState to do this. When you add the controls on the button click event, add the info needed to recreate the controls into the page's viewstate.

A good discussion of these principles can be found here: [Manage Dynamically Created Controls - *Take advantage of automatic state maintenance for dynamic controls.*](http://devproconnections.com/aspnet/manage-dynamically-created-controls)

> To track the controls created dynamically, you must use a persistent data store, such as the view state. A simple trick you can employ consists of adding some information to the page's view state whenever a dynamic control is created. The syntax and semantics of what you add to the view state are completely up to you.

Comment: Thanks. The control is being added on a button click, so it is not possible for me to add event before Form_Load event. Is there anything else that can be done to fire up event?